# How to start a released Asp.net Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm an asp.net developer and recently trying to archive asp.net-core.

Since it's quite new, I would like to ask, how do you launch a asp.net-core project in a Windows machine?

For normal asp.net, my approach is publishing the project using Visual Studio, bring everything to a Windows machine, use IIS to create a website and point the directory to my physical file.

How about a website that created by asp.net-core?

1. Do I need to install asp.net-core in server machine? (i don't prefer this)
2. What should I do with the published file? There are two folders generated after publishing the project:

   - netcoreapp1.0
   - PublishOutput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you still can use the file system mechanism to publish an ASP.NET Core project from Visual Studio. But VS uses the dotnet CLI under the hood to do the same stuff. Usually you configure your deployment depending upon your hosting environment such as Windows Server and Linux Server.

**For Windows Server**

You have to install [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module) in order to publish on IIS successfully. *This will also install .NET Core SDK.* You can than have the advantages of SSL Terminations and others provided by IIS on Windows Server.

**For Linux**

You have to use the .NET Core SDK here as well for a **published** app to acquire the .NET Core runtime (This is why you get those 2 folders). You use Nginx or HAProxy to get all SSL Terminations, Port-Forwarding etc.